# JavaScript: Table data text to form text area

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a sort of primitive type of order form for a school project website. What I have is a table with different items with an "add" button for each and an order form where I want the items to go once the user clicks "add"

Here's what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<tr id="ER-005LP">
    <td>ER-005LP</td>
    <td>Dystopicon - Man Made Earth</td>
    <td>10"</td>
    <td>9€</td>
    <td class="td-add"><button class="add" type="button">Add</button></td>
</tr>

<label for="item-field">Items:</label>
                    <textarea rows="6" name="items" id="item-field"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var element = document.getElementById( "ER-005LP" );
var field = document.getElementById( "item-field" );
var addButton = document.getElementById( "ER-005LP" );

function clickAddButton() {
   ????
}

addButton.onclick = clickAddButton;
```

Any suggestions? I think all I need is to write the correct data in the JS function, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Where's the element into which this data is supposed to be displayed/added?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, here it is:

    `<label for="item-field">Items:</label>
                        <textarea rows="6" name="items" id="item-field"></textarea>
                        <br><br>`

Comment: what is that textarea for?

Comment: @krozero that's where I want the text from the table row "ER-005LP" to go with the click of a button.